# Template matching using Emgu CV - not working for multiple templates

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, opencv3.0

i am working on Emgu CV and i am not getting the result for multiple templates within an image, please check the below code and let me know where i am making a mistake.
i believe i have made a mistake at while loop- kindly correct me what i need to do to get the results.

```
using (Image<Bgr, byte> imgSrc = BaseImage.Copy())
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (Image<Gray, float> result = imgSrc.MatchTemplate(SubImage, TemplateMatchingType.SqdiffNormed))
        {
            CvInvoke.Threshold(result, result, 0.7, 1, ThresholdType.ToZero);
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
            if (maxValues[0] > Threashold)
            {
                Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], SubImage.Size);
                imgSrc.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Blue), -1);
                rectangles.Add(match);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is working and updated the code in comment which i have changed.

```
 using (Image<Bgr, byte> imgSrc = BaseImage.Copy())
    {
        while (true)
        {
           //updated and changed TemplateMatchingType- CcoeffNormed.
            using (Image<Gray, float> result = imgSrc.MatchTemplate(SubImage, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed)) 
            {
                CvInvoke.Threshold(result, result, 0.7, 1, ThresholdType.ToZero);
                double[] minValues, maxValues;
                Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
                result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
                if (maxValues[0] > Threashold)
                {
                    Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], SubImage.Size);
                    imgSrc.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Blue), -1);
                    rectangles.Add(match);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```